# Getting Javascript Object Elements to Appear Next to HTML Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm having trouble with DOM manipulation. I'm trying to make the code below into a working quiz.

How do I associate the possibleAnswers with the buttons in my HTML? And how do I cycle through them when continuing through the quiz onto other questions? I cut out a most of the questions to save space.

Thanks.

Javascript:

```
let q9 = {
question : 'Which of the following films is NOT part of the Walt 
Disney Studios Silly Symphonies?',
possibleAnswers : ['A. The Night Before Christmas',
             'B. Three Little Pigs',
             'C. The Old Mill',
             'D. The Gallopin\' Gaucho'],
flags : [false, false, false, true],
answer : 'D. The Gallopin\' Gaucho'
};

let q10 = {
question : 'Which wartime activity did the Walt Disney Studios 
partake in to support the American war effort?',
possibleAnswers : ['A. Recycling used film footage',
              'B. Designing US Army & US Navy insignia',
              'C. Hosted a Studio Victory Garden where employees grew 
food for their families',
              'D. Forced employees to carpool by closing parking lots 
to non-carpool cars'],
flags : [false, true, false, false],
answer : 'B. Designing US Army & US Navy insignia'
}

 let questionArray = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10];


//hide answer buttons
$("#answers").hide();



 $(function() {


 const answerContainers =

$("#begin_button").on("click", function() {
  $(this).hide()
  $('#insert_question').text(question1.question);
  $("#answers").show()
  $('#insert_question').text(question1.answerSelections);
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="actionmovies.css"/>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css"/>-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js" 
integrity="sha256-laXWtGydpwqJ8JA+X9x2miwmaiKhn8tVmOVEigRNtP4=" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="actionmovies2.js"></script>

<title>Question This: Action Movie Edition</title>
</head>
<header>

</header>
<body>
$( function() {
$( document ).tooltip();
 } );


<h1>Question This: Super Action Movie Edition</h1>
<audio autoplay>
<!-- <source src="audio/intro_music.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> -->
</audio>
<!-- <div class="timer"></div> -->
<div id="quiz_things">
<button class="Begin" id="begin_button" name="Start!" value="Begin 
Trivia"></button>
<div class="question" id="insert_question"><span></span></div>
<div id="answers">
    <div class="choices">
      <input type="button" class="answerOptions" id="choice1">
<h4>1</h4><h3></h3></input>

    <div>
        <input type="button" class="answerOptions" id="choice2">
<h4>2</h4><h3></h3></button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" class="answerOptions" id="choice3">
<h4>3</h4><h3></h3></button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" class="answerOptions" id="choice4">
<h4>4</h4><h3></h3></button>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="answerOptions" id="choice5">
<h4>5</h4><h3></h3></button>
  </div>
  <div id="insert_choices"></div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `question1`, and from what I see are you asigning an `click` event to `answerContainers` constant?

Comment: Ugh. Sorry, this is from a scratch file I was messing around with. `question1` should be `q1`.

Comment: When I wrote: `$('#insert_question').text(question1.answerSelections);` the `answerSelections` for the quiz appeared by the `#choice5`. But it was all the choices for the question. Instead of one choice per number.

Comment: So are you trying to fill in the first question and it's possible answers in the onclick()? I'm not even clear that is the goal. At the moment you are inserting the question and the answers to the same place. And you don't have anything to split out the answers. You need to iterate through them.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to fill the question and possible answers in the onclick()! Sorry for not being clear.